Mock reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient with junit5 and Mockito
Im currently trying to test a class in my Java Spring Boot Application using JUnit5 and Mockito. The problem is that one of the classes method uses the reactor netty HttpClient. I am having some issues mocking the httpclient. I am using an approch from my webclient mock in which i mocked each scall on the httpclient. Now i get following error:
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

my test looks like this:
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMethod;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.netty.ByteBufFlux;
import reactor.netty.ByteBufMono;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockStatic;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class ServiceTest {

    @Spy
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    @Mock
    HttpClient.RequestSender requestSender;
    @Mock
    ByteBufFlux byteBufFlux;
    @Mock
    ByteBufMono byteBufMono;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        httpClient = HttpClient.create();
    }

    @Test
    void testFetchImageFromURLBase64Success() {
        mockStatic( HttpClient.class );
        mockHttpClient();


        var host = "example.com";
        var port = 80;
        var imageUrl = "http://example.com/image.jpg";

        when( httpClient.request( HttpMethod.GET ) )
                .thenReturn( requestSender );

        var res = Service.fetchImageFromURLBase64( host, port, imageUrl );

        assertNotNull( res );
    }

    private void mockHttpClient() {
        var mockImageBytes = new byte[]{ (byte)0x89, (byte)0x50 };


        when( httpClient.request( HttpMethod.GET ) )
                .thenReturn( requestSender );
        when( requestSender.uri( anyString() ) )
                .thenReturn( requestSender );
        when( requestSender.responseContent() )
                .thenReturn( byteBufFlux );
        when( byteBufFlux.aggregate() )
                .thenReturn( byteBufMono );
        when( byteBufMono.asByteArray() )
                .thenReturn( Mono.just( mockImageBytes ) );
    }
}

and the method i want to test which uses the httpclient looks like this:
public static String fetchImageFromURLBase64( String hostName, int port, String imageUrl ) {
        try {
            var httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                    .proxy( p -> p.type( ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP ).host( hostName ).port( port ) );
            var response = httpClient
                    .request( HttpMethod.GET )
                    .uri( imageUrl )
                    .responseContent()
                    .aggregate()
                    .asByteArray()
                    .block();

            if( response == null || response.length == 0 ) {
                log.error( "Could not retrieve image bytes from url: {}", imageUrl );
                return null;
            }

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( response );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            // In case the service returns a 500 we don't want the application to crash
            log.error( "Error retrieving image from URL: {} with error message: ", imageUrl, e );
            return null;
        }
    }

Does anybody know why i get the generic error? Or is there a better/easier approach on mocking the httpclient call?

You are calling when(httpClient.request(HttpMethod.GET)).thenReturn( requestSender); but httpClient is not a mock: httpClient = HttpClient.create();. IMHO mocking is not going to give you much benefit in terms of testing your method - I would think of launching a proxy and a server before launching your test and using a real HttpClient implementation

Your @Spy annotation is useless for two reasons:

Your test is not run with the MockitoExtension, so the annotations are completely ignored
Your setup method reassigns the field and overwrites its value with a real, unspied instance

Assuming you had the Mockito extension loaded:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @Spy
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        httpClient = HttpClient.create();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        // …
    }
}

then what happens when your test executes?

A new instance of ServiceTest is created
All Mockito annotations are picked up by the extension and Mock or Spy objects are created
The httpClient field of the instance is assigned the created Spy object
Your setup method runs, overwriting the reference to the Spy object with a reference to a new, real instance created with HttpClient.create()
Your test cases use a real http client, because the Spy object is no longer accessible from your test class (all its references are gone)

A more detailed explanation and several solutions to the problem can be found in Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?
